# Selecting multiple data from a table and inserting into another table using PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, insert

I've created a form that submits data into multiple tables. My fields are First Name, Last Name, Email, City/Region/Country and they're all inserted into 3 different tables (User, Email, Location).

The data goes into User and Email just fine, but I'm confused about what to do with Location.

I have 3 separate tables for Location (City, Region, Country). What I want to do is insert CityID, RegionID, and CountryID into the Location table. I have the City/Region/Country field set up so it autocompletes based on the city like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYvJG.png]

My Cities table has all the necessary info (CityID, RegionID, CountryID). How can I pull that data from the Cities table and insert it into my Location table?

Here's part of my code. I'm very very new to PHP and MySQL, so I apologize for the sloppiness of this. The first part of the code works, but the 2nd part doesn't (inserting data into the Location table).

```
//Insert static values into people table
$sql_user = sprintf("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName,) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']),
$result_user = $db->query($sql_user);

//get last inserted userid
    $inserted_user_id = $db->last_insert_id();

//Insert values into location table
$sql_city = sprintf("INSERT INTO Location (UserID, CityID, RegionID, CountryID) 
VALUES ('$inserted_user_id',(SELECT CityID, RegionID, CountryID, FROM Cities))");
$result_city = $db->query($sql_city);
```

I figure maybe I need to have "WHERE..." after FROM Cities, but I don't know what my condition would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That condition is up to you. If you're taking the value from the input box, it looks like you need to figure out the best way to read the location from the input field. Taking it as is you might want to first break the input into an array:

```
$location = explode(',',$_POST['location'])
$city = $location[0];
$region = $location[1];
$country = $location[2];
```

Now in your query -

```
"...WHERE city_name = '{$city}' AND region_name = '{$region_name}' AND country_name = '{$country}'";
```

*EDIT

To be more detailed, you need to setup a separate query to get the location by using SQL Joins. Your join combined with the WHERE constraints should return the city you are looking for. So here:

```
"SELECT Cities.CityID,Cities.RegionID,Cities.CountryID FROM Cities JOIN (Regions,Countries) ON Cities.RegionID = Regions.RegionID AND Cities.CountryID = Countries.CountryID WHERE Cities.CityName = '{city}' AND Regions.RegionName = '{$region}' AND Countries.CountryName = '{$country}' LIMIT 1"
```

**UPDATE

This is pretty basic stuff that you can get by looking at the PHP manual on MySQL.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Since you're new, I will grant you a pass.

After you run your this query:

```
$location_result = mysql_query("SELECT Cities.CityID,Cities.RegionID,Cities.CountryID FROM Cities JOIN (Regions,Countries) ON Cities.RegionID = Regions.RegionID AND Cities.CountryID = Countries.CountryID WHERE Cities.CityName = '{$city}' AND Regions.RegionName = '{$region}' AND Countries.CountryName = '{$country}' LIMIT 1");
```

You need to access the result. So:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($location_result)) {
   $cityID =  $location_result['CityID'];
   //etc... for each associative column
}
```

And then in your insert query, insert the $cityID variable for CityID column, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the response, kevin. One concern though - my Cities table doesn't have the Region Name or the Country Name. It only contains the Region ID and Country ID, and I can't just have the condition WHERE city_name = '{$city} because there are several cities with the same name. Do you know how I can work around that problem?

Comment: What are the columns in each of the location tables? City table columns, region columns, etc...

Comment: Cities Table: CityID, CountryID, RegionID, CityName. Regions Table: RegionID, CountryID, RegionName. Countries Table: CountryID, CountryName. I tried your solution, except I left out data about Regions and Countries (only grabbing CityID) and it works perfectly for cities without duplicates. Once there are cities with the same name, I get errors.

Comment: I just tried what you put in your edit and I think I'm definitely on the right track, but I still keep getting different errors depending on what I do. Right now I have this: SELECT Cities.CityID FROM Cities JOIN (Regions,Countries) ON Cities.RegionID = Regions.RegionID AND Cities.CountryID = Countries.CountryID WHERE Cities.CityName = '{$city}' AND Regions.RegionName = '{$region}' AND Countries.CountryName = '{$country}' LIMIT 1. I'm just trying to get the CityID instead of getting RegionID and CountryID too. This is the error I get: "Column 'CityID' cannot be null".

Comment: Okay, you need to be more clear here. You're getting that 'Column CityID' cannot be null on the Insert query.

Comment: Try doing it one step at a time. Comment out the Insert queries and see if you can get a result by just doing the JOIN query that I showed you. If you don't have a result in the database, then you're data constraint is wrong. Get back to me when you get the result from the query. DO NOT DO THE INSERTS yet.

Comment: I tried it out without the INSERTS in the database and I got the correct results. So what you have is absolutely correct. I think what I need to know is how to isolate the CityID.

Comment: Here's my code now: `$location_result = mysql_query("SELECT Cities.CityID,Cities.RegionID,Cities.CountryID FROM Cities JOIN (Regions,Countries) ON Cities.RegionID = Regions.RegionID AND Cities.CountryID = Countries.CountryID WHERE Cities.CityName = '{$city}' AND Regions.RegionName = '{$region}' AND Countries.CountryName = '{$country}' LIMIT 1");

$sql_city = sprintf("INSERT INTO Location (PeopleID, CityID) VALUES ('$inserted_user_id','$location_result')");
$result_city = $db->query($sql_city);`

Comment: I get no php errors with that code, but the only problem is that when the data is put into the Location table, it doesn't pull the correct CityID, which makes sense since $location_results won't give me the CityID.